# Cross table constraints in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, database-design, triggers, constraints, referential-integrity

Using PostgreSQL 9.2.4, I have a table `users` with a 1:many relation to the table `user_roles`. The `users` table stores both employees and other kinds of users.

```
                                       Table "public.users"
    Column       |            Type   |                      Modifiers
-----------------+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------------
 uid             | integer           | not null default nextval('users_uid_seq'::regclass)
 employee_number | character varying |
 name            | character varying |

Indexes:
    "users_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (uid)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "user_roles" CONSTRAINT "user_roles_uid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (uid) REFERENCES users(uid)

                                      Table "public.user_roles"
    Column |            Type   |                            Modifiers
-----------+-------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------
 id        | integer           | not null default nextval('user_roles_id_seq'::regclass)
 uid       | integer           |
 role      | character varying | not null
Indexes:
    "user_roles_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "user_roles_uid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (uid) REFERENCES users(uid)
```

I want to ensure that the column `users.employee_number` cannot be `NULL` if there is a related row where `user_roles.role_name` contains an employee role name. That is, I want the database to enforce the constraint that for some roles, `users.employee_number` must have a value, but not for others.

How can I accomplish this, preferably without user-defined functions or triggers? I found ([blog post](http://spaghettidba.com/2011/08/03/enforcing-complex-constraints-with-indexed-views/), [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16314372/ms-sql-server-cross-table-constraint)) that SQL Server supports indexed views, which sounds like it would serve my purpose. However, I assume that materialized views will not work in my case, since they are not dynamically updated.

Comment: Can you provide more detail on what the columns are?  Perhaps there is another solution to your problem.

Comment: @Gordon Sure, I updated the question to clarify the use case somewhat.

Comment: It would help if you provided table definitions (`\d tbl` in psql) and, as *always*, your version of Postgres.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I updated the question with the requested info for posterity. I also updated the table names to avoid the distracting naming problems, even though this might make your answer look odd. I do appreciate how you keep pointing out these kinds of issues. (Although in my actual DB the names were fine, and I made a mistake when extracting the relevant parts for this question.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Clarification

The formulation of this requirement leaves room for interpretation:
*"where `user_roles.role_name` contains an employee role name."*

My interpretation:
*"with an entry in `user_roles` that has `role_name = 'employee'`."*

#### The problem

`FOREIGN KEY` and `CHECK` constraints are proven, air-tight tools to enforce relational integrity. Triggers are powerful, versatile features but more sophisticated, less strict, and with more room for design errors and corner cases.

A FK constraint seems impossible for your case at first: it requires a `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE` constraint to reference - neither allows NULL values. There are no partial FK constraints. The only escape from strict referential integrity are `null` values in *referencing* columns - with default **`MATCH SIMPLE`** behavior of FK constraints. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html)

> `MATCH SIMPLE` allows any of the foreign key columns to be null; if any
> of them are null, the row is not required to have a match in the referenced table.

See:

- [Two-column foreign key constraint only when third column is NOT NULL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/54402/3684)

The workaround is to introduce a boolean flag `is_employee` to mark employees on both sides, defined `NOT NULL` in `users`, but allowed to be `NULL` in `user_roles`:

#### Solution

This enforces your requirements ***exactly***, while keeping noise and overhead to a minimum:

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (
  users_id    serial PRIMARY KEY
, employee_nr int
, is_employee bool NOT NULL DEFAULT false
, CONSTRAINT role_employee CHECK (employee_nr IS NOT NULL = is_employee)  
, UNIQUE (is_employee, users_id)  -- required for FK (otherwise redundant)
);

CREATE TABLE user_roles (
  user_roles_id serial PRIMARY KEY
, users_id      int NOT NULL REFERENCES users
, role_name     text NOT NULL
, is_employee   bool CHECK(is_employee)
, CONSTRAINT role_employee CHECK (role_name <> 'employee' OR is_employee IS TRUE)
, CONSTRAINT role_employee_requires_employee_nr_fk
  FOREIGN KEY (is_employee, users_id) REFERENCES users(is_employee, users_id)
);
```

That's all.

#### Optional triggers for convenience

The following triggers are optional, but recommended for convenience to set the added tags `is_employee` automatically and you don't have to do *anything* extra:

```sql
-- users
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_users_insup_bef()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   NEW.is_employee := (NEW.employee_nr IS NOT NULL);
   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$;

CREATE TRIGGER insup_bef
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF employee_nr ON users
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION trg_users_insup_bef();


-- user_roles
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_user_roles_insup_bef()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   NEW.is_employee = true;
   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$;

CREATE TRIGGER insup_bef
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF role_name ON user_roles
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.role_name = 'employee')
EXECUTE FUNCTION trg_user_roles_insup_bef();
```

No-nonsense, optimized and only called when needed.
(Before Postgres 11, use the (misleading) [key word `PROCEDURE`.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/307500/3684) instead,)

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/D4CgvD_f)
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a2c3d/8). (Works with ancient Postgres 9.1, too.)</sub>

#### Major points

Now, if we want to set `user_roles.role_name = 'employee'`, then there has to be a matching `user.employee_nr` first.

You can still add an `employee_nr` to *any* user, and you can (then) still tag any `user_roles` with `is_employee`, regardless of the actual `role_name`. Easy to disallow if you need to, but this implementation does not introduce any more restrictions than required.

**`users.is_employee`** can only be `true` or `false` and is forced to reflect the existence of an `employee_nr` by the `CHECK` constraint. The trigger keeps the column in sync automatically. You could allow `false` additionally for other purposes with only minor updates to the design.

The rules for **`user_roles.is_employee`** are slightly different: it must be `true` if `role_name = 'employee'`. Enforced by a `CHECK` constraint and set automatically by the trigger again. But it's allowed to change `role_name` to something else and still keep `is_employee`. Nobody said a user with an `employee_nr` is *required* to have an according entry in `user_roles`, just the other way round! Again, easy to enforce additionally if needed.

If there are other triggers that could interfere, consider:

- [How To Avoid Looping Trigger Calls In PostgreSQL 9.2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13663926/how-to-avoid-looping-trigger-calls-in-postgresql-9-2-1/13665973#13665973)

But we need not worry that rules might be violated by the triggers. The requested rules are enforced with `CHECK` and FK constraints, which allow no exceptions.

Aside: I put the column `is_employee` first in the constraint `UNIQUE (is_employee, users_id)` *for a reason*. `users_id` is already covered in the PK, so it can take second place here:

- [DB associative entities and indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335312/db-associative-entities-and-indexing/10336270#10336270)

Comment: . . I interpret "to enforce the constraint that for some roles" as being broader than just a single role called "employee".  My interpretation was that there is a flag that says that an employee number is needed, not a particular role known in advance.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: That may be. Either way, the flag you mention would be the same as `user_role.is_employee` in my design, which would make it a simpler subset of this solution.

Comment: Regarding the interpretation of "some roles", Gordon Linoff is correct. As pointed out, this actually makes the solution simpler.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter This solves my problem. Thanks! Took me a little time and reading to understand the `MATCH SIMPLE` behaviour. This led me to think that I may specify roles that are "unemployable" by setting `user_role.is_employee = false`. Which works, if I remove the `CHECK(is_employee)` from `user_role.is_employee`. Why did you put that check there in the first place?

Comment: @DagHøidahl: I put it in, because there was no request for "unemployable user_roles". As I mentioned, the design can easily be extended - just like you did.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter There probably won't be any need for "unemployable users" either, so that's an impressive attention to detail.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter . . . As usual, you give a very thorough and well-explained answer.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can solve this using a trigger.

But, I think you can solve this using constraints, with just a little weirdness:

```
create table UserRoles (
    UserRoleId int not null primary key,
    . . .
    NeedsEmployeeNumber boolean not null,
    . . .
);

create table Users (
    . . .
    UserRoleId int,
    NeedsEmployeeNumber boolean,
    EmployeeNumber,
    foreign key (UserRoleId, NeedsEmployeeNumber) references UserRoles(UserRoleId, NeedsEmployeeNumber),
    check ((NeedsEmployeeNumber and EmployeeNumber is not null) or
           (not NeedsEmployeeNumber and EmployeeNumber is null)
          )
);
```

This should work, but it is an awkward solution:

- When you add a role to an employee, you need to add the flag along with the role.
- If a role is updated to change the flag, then this needs to be propagated to existing records -- and the propagation cannot be automatic because you also need to potentially set `EmployeeNumber`.

Comment: I think this is going in the right direction with check and fk constraints, but doesn't go all the way. A clean solution is possible.

Answer (score 0):

New Answer:

This( [SQL Sub queries in check constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179121/sql-sub-queries-in-check-constraint) ) seems to answer your question, and the language is still in the 9.4 documentation( http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/sql-createtable.html ).

Old Answer:

```
SELECT 
  User.*
  , UserRole1.*
FROM
 User
  LEFT JOIN UserRole UserRole1 
    ON User.id = UserRole1.UserId 
     AND (
      (
       User.employee_number IS NOT NULL AND UserRole1.role_name IN (enumerate employee role names here)
      ) 
     OR 
      (User.employee_number IS NULL)
     )
```

The above query selects all fields from `User` and all fields from `UserRole`(aliased as UserRole1).  I assumed that the key field between the two fields is known as User.id and U`serRole1.UserId`, please change these to whatever the real values are.

In the `JOIN` part of the query there is an OR that on the left side requires an employee number not be `NULL` in the user table and that *UserRole1.role_name be in a list that you must supply* to the `IN ()` operator.

The right part of the `JOIN` is the opposite, it requires that `User.employee_number` be `NULL`(this should be your non-employee set).

If you require a more exact solution then please provide more details on your table structures and what roles must be selected for employees.

Comment: Sorry if my question was not clear enough, but I was looking for a *constraint*, not a query.